# Adjoint matrix question: do I change the elements to +/-?

Tags: matrices

Lets say

$A =
\begin{pmatrix}
 -1& 3&  4\\
 -4&  1&  0\\
 3&  1&  -1
\end{pmatrix}
$

When I calculate the adjoint of A, I get

$
adj(A) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
          -1&  7&   -4\\
         -4& -11& -16\\
         -7&  10&  11
\end{pmatrix}
$

I get this by transposing A and then taking the cofactor of each element. However, in my textbook the answer is the same but all the signs are opposite. I checked using an online adjoint calculator and I received the same answer that I worked out, but Matlab gives the same answer as the text book. Really confused.

Comment: Whatever you decide to call each step of the process, the end result is that at some point in the process of finding inverse using cofactors in this method you take the hadamard product with the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}+&-&+&\dots\\-&+&-&\dots\\+&-&\dots\\\vdots\end{bmatrix}$, flipping the signs of the matrix in a checkerboard fashion.  Whether you choose do that before or after depends on how you are taught.  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) has the "checkerboard sign switch" step built into the cofactor step (*present as the coefficient $(-1)^{i+j}$*)

Comment: That's exactly what I did - taking into account the (-1)^i+j,  but my answer and the textbook's answer are different. I thought that the textbook may simply be wrong, but Matlab has the same answer of the textbook.

Comment: Look at exactly how your textbook words the process and follow how it is written there.